# Installing DroidExplorer 0.9.0.0.0 32 bit version on Windows 7 error

Tags: windows-7, installation, android

Good day! I am trying to copy files to my Android root directory, I can not do it with an application because the root explorers I tried do not work, so I want to install DroidExplorer for PC and do it.

I run into the following error:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried installing as an administrator?

Comment: Yes! More than once. I tried installing it on the Desktop also. Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that I am trying to install it on a virtual machine since on my host OS there was a problem with the service which does not want to start and no matter what I do i does not start. My host OS is windows 8, 64bit. My guest OS is Windows 7 starter on VmWare player 12.